# Ошибка при аутентификации в Spring Security

Tags: java, postgresql, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Всем привет! Пытаюсь победить аутентификацию в Spring Security, но она оказалась сильнее))
При попытке входа меня перенаправляет не на страницу, которую я указал, а вместо этого на ту же страницу с параметром "?error". Пароль в БД добавляется, шифруется, но на этом пока все

Класс PersonConfig

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com/example")
public class PersonConfig{
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres");
        dataSource.setUsername("postgres");
        dataSource.setPassword("1");
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

Класс SecurityConfig

```
import com.example.TempFile.repository.PersonRepository;
import com.example.TempFile.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(PersonRepository userRepo) {
        return new UserService();
    }
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((autorize) -> autorize
                                .requestMatchers("/home", "/person").authenticated()
                                .requestMatchers("/", "/**").permitAll())
                                .formLogin(form -> form.loginPage("/loging")
                                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/home"));
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Класс PersonController

```
import com.example.TempFile.model.Person;
import com.example.TempFile.repository.PersonRepository;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Controller
public class PersonController {

    private final PersonRepository personRepository;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public PersonController(PersonRepository personRepository, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.personRepository = personRepository;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String getHome(Model model) {
        Iterable<Person> personList = personRepository.findAll();
        List<Person> p = new ArrayList<>();
        personList.forEach(p::add);
        model.addAttribute("persons", p);
        model.addAttribute("message", "hihihihihi");
        return "home";
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String getLogin() {
        return "loging";
    }

    @GetMapping("/loging")
    public String getLoging() {
        return "loging";
    }

    @GetMapping("/pesron")
    public String getPerson() {
        return "person";
    }

    @PostMapping("/loging")
    public String postLoging(@RequestParam String username, @RequestParam String password) {
        Optional<Person> person = personRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if (person != null && username.equals(person.get().getUsername()) && passwordEncoder.matches(password, person.get().getPassword())) {
            return "person";
        }
        return "redirect:/loging";
    }

    @GetMapping("/home/{id}")
    public String getPerson(@PathVariable long id, Model model) {
        Person person = personRepository.findById(id).get();
        model.addAttribute("person", person);
        model.addAttribute("firstName", person.getUsername());
        return "person";
    }

}
```

Класс RegisterController

```
import com.example.TempFile.model.Person;
import com.example.TempFile.repository.PersonRepository;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/register")
public class RegisterController {
    private PersonRepository repository;
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public RegisterController(PersonRepository repository, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.repository = repository;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String registerForm(){
        return  "register";
    }
    @PostMapping
    public String processRegistration(@RequestParam String username, @RequestParam String password){
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setUsername(username);
        person.setPassword(password);
        //Необходимо установить роль юзера
        person.setRoles("ROLE_USER");
        person.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(person.getPassword()));
        repository.save(person);
        return "redirect:/loging";
    }
}
```

Модель Person

```
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String roles;

}
```

Модель PersonDetails

```
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class PesronDetails implements UserDetails {

    private Person person;

    public PesronDetails(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
        //Не думаю, что это ошибка, но мне больше этой роли не нужно было
        /*return Arrays.stream(person.getRoles().split(", "))
                .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());*/
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return person.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return person.getUsername();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Интерфейс PersonRepository

```
import com.example.TempFile.model.Person;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import java.util.Optional;

public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {
    Optional<Person> findByUsername(String username);
}
```

Класс UserService

```
import com.example.TempFile.model.Person;
import com.example.TempFile.model.PesronDetails;
import com.example.TempFile.repository.PersonRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;


    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional<Person> person = personRepository.findByUsername(username);
        return person.map(PesronDetails::new).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found"));
    }
}
```

Страница входа loging.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Taco Cloud</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Login</h1>
<p>New here? Click
    <a th:href="@{/register}">here</a> to register.</p>
<form method="post" th:action="@{/loging}" id="loginForm">
    <label for="username">Username: </label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" /><br/>
    <label for="password">Password: </label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" /><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Страница регистрации register.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Taco Cloud</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Register</h1>
<img th:src="@{/images/TacoCloud.png}"/>
<form method="POST" th:action="@{/register}" id="registerForm">
    <label for="username">Username: </label>
    <input type="text" name="username"/><br/>
    <label for="password">Password: </label>
    <input type="password" name="password"/><br/>

    <input type="submit" value="Register"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Домашняя страница home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>HELLO EVERYBODY!!!</h1>
<p th:text="${message}"></p>
    <tr th:each="person: ${persons}" >
        <a th:href="@{/home/{id}(id=${person.getId()})}"><td th:text="${person.id}" ></td></a>
        <td th:text="${person.username}" ></td><br /><br /><br />
    </tr>

<form action="/" method="post">
    Enter password: <input type="password" name="password" /><br />
    <button type="submit">Log in</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Страница человека person.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>HELLO <span th:text="${userame}">name</span></h1>
<p th:text="${ID}"></p>
<p th:text="${userame}"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Файл application.properties

```
db.URL=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
db.username=postgres
db.password=1
```

Comment: Очень много кода, во всём сложно разобраться. Вы используете Spring Boot и, соответственно, имеете возможность настраивать работу с БД при помощи `.properties`-файла. Бин `PersonConfig` вам не нужен. Только названия ключей в проперти замените соответственно на `spring.datasource.url`, `spring.datasource.username` и `spring.datasource.password`. Далее, в security-конфиг-классе уберите аннотацию `@EnableWebSecurity`.  Опять же, вы используете Spring Boot, и поэтому многие аннотации по включению тех или иных работ не только излишни, но и могут приводить к ошибкам.

Comment: Похоже не то, что PasswordEncoder существует как отдельный бин в спринге и не используется при логине пользователя, поэтому перенаправляет на ?error при несовпадении паролей. Можно попробовать не хешировать пароли (`NoOpPasswordEncoder` вместо `BCryptPasswordEncoder`). Если есть возможность посмотреть дебагом сравнение паролей, то будет вообще отлично.

Comment: @Byb, да, настройку работы с БД в .properties файле намного удобнее проводить, просто я изначально в Н2 тренировался, чтобы лишнего не подключать, а потом решил проверить, сохраняется ли действительно Person в БД (в н2-console меня, почему-то, не пускало). Спасибо, пошел исправлять!

Comment: @MrFylypenko, так задача как раз добиться шифрования пароля и успешного входа после регистрации

Comment: Я могу предположить, что вход не происходит потому, что при регистрации я не присваиваю пользователю роль и сам пользователь ее не указывает. Но, с другой стороны, в SecurityConfig доступ на определенные страницы возможен не определенной роли (типа hasRole()) а с условием authenticated(). Тогда вопрос: когда пользователь считается аутентифицированным? Просто я видел, как разработчики строят свои приложения со входом без токена, но тут, кажется, что он нужен. Или я не прав?

Comment: Ошибка найдена! Как всегда, банальная невнимательность. В классе PersonDetails, а конкретно в методе getAuthorities() необходимо было четко указать, какая роль должна быть у пользователя для прохода дальше(исправленный код добавлю, ошибочный укажу в комментарии), но дальше смешнее... При регистрации пользователя в базу сохраняется объект класса Person  БЕЗ какого-либо указания роли. В моем классе SecurityConfig нет метода hasAutority(), но метод аутентификации у меня настроен именно по роли пользователя, от этого меня и не пускали дальше loging?error. Спасибо всем, кто подсказывал!